# css height in mozilla e chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, mozilla

I have this code, a little dirty but functional.
Ie on safari and no problem but on chrome and mozilla not know why the parameters height and line-height change value.

height: 3.125em! important; -> IE = 50px SAFARI - MOZ CHROME = 132px
line-height: 3.438em; -> IE = 55px SAFARI - MOZ CHROME = 132px

This is the source:

```
$html  = '<td data-date="'.$year.'-'.$month.'-'.$date.'" class="'.implode(' ',$classes).'" style="height:3.125em !important;">';
$html .= '<span class="date'.($appointments_left ? ' tooltipster" title="'.sprintf( _n('%d time slot','%d time slots',$appointments_left,'booked'), $appointments_left) : '"').'" style="height:3.125em !important; line-height: 3.438em !important;">';
$html .= '<span class="number" >'. $date .'</span></span>';
$html .= '</td>';
```

interpreted by IE and Safari

```
<td data-date="2015-09-31" class="blur" style="height: 3.125em !important;">
<span class="date" "="" style="height: 3.125em !important; line-height: 3.438em !important;">
<span class="number">31</span>
</span>
</td>
```

starring chrome and mozilla

```
<td data-date="2015-09-31" class="blur" style="height: 132px;">
<span class="date" "="" style="height: 3.125em ! important; line-height: 132px;">
<span class="number">31</span>
</span>
</td>
```

thanks to those who respond

Comment: You've got problems with unescaped quotes. Also, your date of 2015-09-31 makes me itch.

Comment: This code is a wordpress plugin, I want to change the graphic with those changes. indentation is the fault of the wrong generation ... I'm trying to correct it

Comment: i solved the problem. in This plugin was present js which modified the height of the box

Comment: Ah, OK. You should work on the code that causes the `"=""` to appear in the source though, and check how the date cam become 2015-09-31.